# Customising an implementation of Repository and Unit Of Work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 project I have carefully followed the design principles in this example of implementing Repository and Unit Of Work.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am particularly interested in this remark on the article, written after showing the Generic Repository:

> This generic repository will handle typical CRUD requirements. When a particular entity type has special requirements, such as more complex filtering or ordering, you can create a derived class that has additional methods for that type.

Since my app meets that particular case, I tried to do this. I made a GenericRepository just like the one in the article, and a SharedContext class (SharedContext is exactly the UnitOfWork class in the article, but this name makes more sense to me)

GenericRepository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

namespace BusinessLogicLayer.Repositories
{
public class GenericRepository<T> where T: class
{
    internal DbSet<T> _dbSet;
    internal DBConnection _context;

    #region constructors

    public GenericRepository(SharedContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx.Context;
    }

    public GenericRepository(DBConnection context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

SharedContext (Unit of work) class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BusinessLogicLayer.Repositories
{
public class SharedContext : IDisposable
{
    #region repositories
    private GenericRepository<Entities.Customer> _customerRepository;
    /// <summary>
    /// access the Customer entity
    /// </summary>
    public GenericRepository<Entities.Customer> CustomerRepository
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_customerRepository == null)
                _customerRepository = new GenericRepository<Entities.Customer>(_context);

            return _customerRepository;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    
    #region context management 
    
    private Entities.DBConnection _context = new Entities.DBConnection();
    internal Entities.DBConnection Context { get { return _context; } }
    //other methods - save, delete
    #endregion
}
}
```

Now here is the problem: note how I exposed the Context property above - I have doubts that this is actually intended, I feel like I'm breaking the pattern by doing it. I like a lot the idea that  everything is controlled through the repository in the same context and all, but I need some further methods which are not offered by the generic repository - so I made a separate CustomerRepository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BusinessLogicLayer.Repositories 
{
public class CustomerRepository: GenericRepository<Entities.Customer>
{
    public CustomerRepository(SharedContext ctx)
        : base(ctx)
    {  }
    
    public decimal GetCustomerBonusByFrequency()
    {
        //
        
    }
}
}
```

...which in my controller class, I use like this:

```
private SharedContext ctx = new SharedContext();

public PartialViewResult CustomerBonus()
{
   CustomerRepository cRepo = new CustomerRepository(ctx);
   var bonus = cRepo.GetCustomerBonusByFrequency();
   return PartialView(bonus);
}
```

So my 2 questions are:

- List item

  is this the intended way of adding extra functionality, that was mentioned in the article? Im referring to the class CustomRepository, which feels like a breaking of pattern to me, since there already was a way to get the Customer through GenericRepository(that I am not using anymore), plus I'm exposing the context.
- If this is bad, then how should I do it correctly? all i need is to have the extra methods for my Customer entity, but in a way that respects the pattern.

Thx,

edit:

I needed to expose the Context property in SharedContext, because if I delete that constructor in GenericRepository (that takes a SharedContext) and the :base(ctx) in CustomerRepository class, I get this:

> BusinessLogicLayer.DBModel.Customer  does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a specialized customer repository is the correct thing to do. I would suggest that your `SharedContext` class should be updated such that the `CustomerRepository` property returns an instance of the `CustomerRepository` class, and not of `GenericRepository<Cutomer>`.

This way, when you access the `CustomerRepository` property from the `SharedContext`, you will have the methods of the generic repository available as well as the specialized methods of your `CustomerRepository` class.

Comment: yes, of course, that was it! it makes perfect sense. the sharedcontext  routes entities either through the generic repository, or through the special classes. works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace Demo.DAL
{
    public class Repository<TObject>

        where TObject : class
    {
        protected DB Context;
        protected DB Context = null;
        private bool shareContext = false;

        public Repository()
        {
            Context = new DB();
        }

        public Repository(DB context)
        {
            Context = context;
            shareContext = true;
        }

        protected DbSet<TObject> DbSet
        {
            get
            {
                return Context.Set<TObject>();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (shareContext && (Context != null))
                Context.Dispose();
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TObject> All()
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable();
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TObject> 
        Filter(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate).AsQueryable<TObject>();
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TObject> Filter(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> filter,
         out int total, int index = 0, int size = 50)
        {
            int skipCount = index * size;
            var _resetSet = filter != null ? DbSet.Where(filter).AsQueryable() : 
                DbSet.AsQueryable();
            _resetSet = skipCount == 0 ? _resetSet.Take(size) : 
                _resetSet.Skip(skipCount).Take(size);
            total = _resetSet.Count();
            return _resetSet.AsQueryable();
        }

        public bool Contains(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Count(predicate) > 0;
        }

        public virtual TObject Find(params object[] keys)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(keys);
        }

        public virtual TObject Find(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public virtual TObject Create(TObject TObject)
        {
            var newEntry = DbSet.Add(TObject);
            if (!shareContext)
                Context.SaveChanges();
            return newEntry;
        }

        public virtual int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return DbSet.Count();
            }
        }

        public virtual int Delete(TObject TObject)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(TObject);
            if (!shareContext)
                return Context.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }

        public virtual int Update(TObject TObject)
        {
            var entry = Context.Entry(TObject);
            DbSet.Attach(TObject);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (!shareContext)
                return Context.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }

        public virtual int Delete(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var objects = Filter(predicate);
            foreach (var obj in objects)
                DbSet.Remove(obj);
            if (!shareContext)
                return Context.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```